# DateTime Arithmetic Query Using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have a table contains various columns including two DateTime column, *Start* and *End*.

How can I write a linq query over entity framework to find *Duration*.

I'm looking for a result like this: *2y 3m 2d 6h 4m 58s*.

There's also three important limitations:

1. I can't add function or sp to db
2. I can't add new calculated column to table
3. I can't do this operation in memory using loops like `foreach` considering memory usage according to the huge number of records.

Any idea?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the third point. What are you doing with the results of the query afterwards? You can add a projection to be executed in-process afterwards, and still stream through the data.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I can't calculate the duration using linq to object after fetching data.

Comment: Why not? Just stating it as a fact isn't helpful - if you can explain *why* you believe you can't, we may be able to correct some misunderstanding. Or it's possible that you really can't, but then we'll understand why you can't.

Comment: ...according to the huge number of records and server memory usage.

Comment: @JonSkeet - If he wanted to retrieve records where duration is greater than x, than he would need to calculate duration for every record

Comment: @Reza: You can stream the results. I'm not suggesting you need to do anything with the whole thing in memory. What are you doing with the results *after* you've created the query?

Comment: @Aducci: Indeed, that would be a perfectly good reason. Unfortunately, the OP hasn't chosen to give anything so precise. If the values are *only* needed on the client side, then they can be computed on the client side. Just saying "according to the huge number of records" is no reason at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm sorting duration and show them up.

Comment: @Reza: Okay, so you need the ordering to be executed server-side. It would have been useful to just say that to start with, instead of being vague about it. Does it have to be sorted in genuinely calendar-centric fashion? For example, consider February 1st to March 1st in 2011. That's exactly 28 days - but it's also 1 month and 0 days. Do you definitely want that to come before March 1st to March 30th, which is 0 months and 29 days? It's a longer amount of elapsed time than the first period, but it's fewer months.

Comment: Yes, you're right. What do you suggest then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Linq-to-entities` query, you can use [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) and the the [DiffSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395607.aspx) method to find the difference between two DateTime's

Comment: Quick heads up that EntityFunctions has been deprecated in EF 6.0 and replaced with DbFunctions.